# WKWebView with Basic auth

Tags: ios, authentication, wkwebview, swift5, xcode11

I'm trying to create a simple app with a website embedded using `WebView`, everything works fine except that I don't understand how I would authenticate against a website that requires credentials.
I've searched the web for several hours and finally given up on finding an answer. Might just be that I don't know what wording to use.
Hope anyone on here knows a way either to hardcode the credentials or preferably a way for the user to enter their own credentials.

**Thank you!**

**The code I'm using is the easiest possible, as follows:**

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://siteurl")!))
            }.navigationBarTitle("Example Text")
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `webView(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)` callback from the `WKNavigationDelegate`. From there you can enter credentials and authenticate against the webpage.

You can implement it like the following (pseudo code):

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable, WKNavigationDelegate {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        return webView
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                 completionHandler: @escaping(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let credential = URLCredential(user: "username",
                                       password: "password",
                                       persistence: .forSession)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    }
}
```

Read more here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455638-webview

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I must be doing something wrong cause adding that code gives me errors. Also tried to adapt the code to what I've already got without success.

Comment: Yes, that's possible since it's a quick draft I wrote. When I have time I will try to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, have u had the time to look at the code once more? I'm unfortunately not managing to get it working. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: UIViewRepresentable has to required functions called: makeUIView and updateUIView, You did not show where and how we can call your func called webView!

Answer (score 0):

The `WKNavigationDelegate` must be a class, not a struct. Override `makeCoordinator()` in `UIViewRepresentable` to bind the `WKWebView` to a `WKNavigationDelegate`. See [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126986).