# WKWebView or WebView : How to render a basic auth challenge similar to how Safari does?

Tags: ios, authentication, basic-authentication

I've searched and have not found any answer that doesn't involved handling the credentials in `webView(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)`

My goal is to render the same auth challenge that occurs in Safari or any other browser so that my code doesn't have to touch the user's credentials.

You can see a sample challenge by visiting https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/username/password in any browser

Is this even possible?

For clarity:
If you visit the link above in a normal browser, an auth challenge is displayed/rendered. If you do so in a `WKWebView`, nothing is displayed. You sit at a white screen.

I'm trying to determine the difference in those behaviors, such as why is it rendered in a normal browser but not web view? Is it the browser that renders the challenge, or is it part of the web content of the URL being visited?

Finally, can Basic Auth be done in `WKWebView` (or `WebView`) in such a way as my code doesn't touch the user credentials, because it's the web server handling it via the content displayed in those views?

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you want to achieve. If you want your app to access some web service that needs basic auth credentials then your app needs to get the username and password from the user. If you want the user to authenticate to your app using some existing credentials then you are probably looking for oauth.

Comment: Question edited to provide more detailed context to answer your question @Paulw11

Comment: Ok. The answer is your app needs to collect the user credentials and present them via the web view delegate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508114/wkwebview-with-basic-auth  There is no in-built credential prompt in WKWebView.  Alternatively, see if SFSafariViewController meets your needs

Comment: @Paulw11 SFSafariViewController works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Paulw11, `SFSafariViewController` is the answer.